# What is the meaning of subsections in `Dependencies` section when using `brew info package`?

Tags: dependencies, homebrew

I want to know what are dependencies of some package in brew. That's why I used `brew info package`. Section *Dependencies* contains two subsections *Build* and *Required*. What do these sections mean?

P.S. Is there a way to install package with all its dependencies in brew?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to install packages using Homebrew:

1. Using pre-built binaries (if they are available for your macOS version)
2. Building from source

*Required* dependencies are always needed regardless of how the package is installed. *Build* dependencies are only needed if you are installing the package from source.

By default, Homebrew installs pre-built binaries. (See [FAQ ¶ Why do you compile everything?](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-do-you-compile-everything) and [¶ Why should I install Homebrew in the default location?](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-should-i-install-homebrew-in-the-default-location))

> Is there a way to install package with all its dependencies in brew?

`brew install package` will automatically install dependencies (in addition to installing the package itself).